# Receiving Invalid database URL while trying to start chainlink node

Tags: chainlink

I am trying to start a chainlink node in rinkeby testnet.I have setup a postgres DB in AWS. The Database URL is already given. Below is the error while i am trying to start the node.

```
[ERROR] invalid database url %spostgresql://postgres:Bounty2000%@database-1.ciiecd8szsuh.us-west-1.rd
s.amazonaws.com:5432/db_sar_rinkeby orm/config.go:283 

[ERROR] failed to initialize database, got error failed to connect to `host=/tmp user=root database=`
: dial error (dial unix /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432: connect: no such file or directory) orm/orm.go:82 

[ERROR] failed to initialize database, got error failed to connect to `host=/tmp user=root database=`
: dial error (dial unix /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432: connect: no such file or directory) orm/orm.go:82
```

I tried changing few settings from AWS front but nothing helped.. If anyone have any clue pls help me up.

Answer (score 0):

[Based on the documentation](https://docs.chain.link/docs/connecting-to-a-remote-database/) it looks like there may be an "s" in front of your postgres URL, try removing that in your .env file. Also try replacing the database name with the IP address+Port. What should replace $DATABASE is "postgres". Finally try adding in ?sslmode=disable if you don't have ssl activated at the database (not recommended for a production node).

Example in .env:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://me1234:password1234@10.10.100.100:3000/postgres?sslmode=disable
```

Comment: I get the same error which appends `%s` to my postgres url. This solution does not help